# comprobar si un objeto está en la lista

Tags: python, lista

Estoy aprendiendo a programar, y en un ejercicio, nos han mandado hacer un combate por turnos, y he escogido de tema pokemon.

Queria hacer que el jugador numero 1, pudiera escoger entre 6 pokemons, asignandoles los stats, y ataques,
(y el jugador 2, la maquina, con un equipo predefinido)

Mi pregunta es, cuando pongo un input para seleccionar el pokemon como una 'str' dentro de un while, nunca salgo porque no se como hacer, que este dentro de la lista, por ejemplo:

```py
lista = [aaaa, bbbb, cccc, dddd, eeee]

pokemon_escogido = str(input('escoja su pokemon'))

while pokemon_escogido != lista:
  
 print('escoja un pokemon dentro de la lista')
 pokemon_escogido = str(input('Escoja un pokemon'))

 if pokemon_escogido == lista:
 
  print('desea escoger otro pokemon?')
```

Mi pregunta es, hay algun modo de que la variable (pokemon_escogido) pueda ser igual que solo una palabra dentro del diccionario y salir de ese while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puede verificar si un objeto está en la lista usando `in`

```
while pokemon_escogido not in lista:
... 
if pokemon_escogido in lista:
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por resolverme este problema.

Le estoy muy agradecido